# Is there any solution to have JVM load classes form JARs with LZMA compression?

Tags: java, jar, jvm, lzma

I'm wondering if there is any plan for `JVM` to directly use `JAR` files which have `LZMA/LZMA2` compression on class/module path. As of `JDK 17.0.1`, I don't seem to be able to find a solution, or maybe I've just been searching with wrong keywords.

I'm fully aware of the added runtime overhead for decompression and I'm familiar with the nature of problems with archives based on `LZMA`. But, since `LZMA/LZMA2` gives superior compression ratio compared to a plain-old-ZIP file, I've been doing this on my own for a while for deploying my applications.

The process is straight forward:

1. Produce the `JAR` file/files with `ANT/Maven/manually`
2. Extract each `JAR` file into a separate folder
3. Compress contents of the folder into a similarly named `7z` file (using 7-zip, of course)
4. Bundle them in a installer and deploy
5. After installation, use a custom and small bootstrapper and helper class-loader which reads these `7z` files at runtime and load classes from these archives to execute on `JVM`.

This is not a big deal or hassle, but saves me around **50~60%** of final deployed installer and installed size on disk. The runtime overhead, to my experience, is negligible, as it is just a one time issue per loaded class file.

It is not ideal for a serverless solution, but a Web backend can nicely get around it. For performance critical tasks, the installer recreates the `JAR`s or even explodes them and avoids the bootstrapper/class-loader altogether.

I'm actually looking for a solution or a JSR which integrates this feature within `JDK`.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd need to write your own class-loader based on the jar class loader. I'd also give your not-jar files a different extension so the regular jar class loader doesn't try to load one of your files and break.

Comment: Yes, I've already done that and my LZMA JARs have JARZ extension. I'm seeking a JVM integrated solution.

Comment: I wouldn’t waste any development effort on something that gains you 50 to 60% space saving. The first thing to check, is how much you gain from putting the ordinary jar file into another zip/jar file. When I do this with the `rt.jar` from JDK 8 (62 MiB), the resulting jar file has 20 MiB. Which means 67% gain without the need to write extra software and an easy reversal at the target environment; just extract the jar again…

Comment: Speaking in Information Theory context, source compression reduces redundancy and increases entropy. Therefore, sequential application of source compression will not have the effect of their joint or separate application.

Comment: In this context, when a JAR file is compressed with 7z (since ZIP has already taken away its redundancy to some extent, you wont get the same result if you compress its exploded contents using 7z. And it really depends on how much ZIP has tried to remove redundancy. When lower ZIP compression levels are chosen, there is plenty of redundancy.

Comment: For the case of `rt.jar` on `JDK1.8.0_221` as it is a `PACK200` packaging only, it has no compression at all! That is why you get a huge difference, even with simple ZIP. Here are the stats, `rt.jar` is `60.7 MB`, compressing it with 7z (LZMA2/Ultra) and it shrinks to `12.3 MB`. Extracting it and compressing the contents gives `12.0 MB`. The last two results are is inline with the fact that there is plenty of redundancy for LZMA to play with.

Comment: But the JAR I see produced are not usually a mere `PACK200`, I see compression levels ranging from `3` to `9`.

Comment: You won't find a solution for rt.jar because from Java 9 onwards there is no longer an rt.jar (and I doubt that anyone will want to implement it for Java 8 only). And for your own jar files the solution with the custom class loader should be sufficient.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Please note that my question is not about `Java 8` nor `rt.jar`, I was just answering @Holger

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java class ad hoc compression tool: Pack200. It should compress even more than LZMA because it was designed specifically for .class archives.

You can find more here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/pack200.html

and here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/Pack200.html

Comment: I'm aware of this classic tool, but Pack200 is deprecated, you can find relevant JEP here https://openjdk.org/jeps/336